# javascript command in php not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm getting into an html "echo" of php code and javascript. But it does not work.

```
echo '<select onchange="document.getElementById(\'ele\').innerhtml=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">';
            echo "<option value='Users'>Usuarios</option>";
            echo "<option value='Bots'>Bots</option>";
        echo "</select>";

        echo "<p id='ele'>Elección</p>";
```

Comment: _"But it does not work."_ - And what _does_ happen? Do you get an error in the browser's console?

Comment: `innerhtml` should be `innerHTML` case Matters!

Comment: @nnnnnn no close-vote from you yet? Why so?

Comment: "It does not work" does not describe a specific problem; are you seeing errors? Or can you describe the expected and actual behaviour? Also, have you tried simplifying the problem to just HTML and JS, without the PHP, to see if the PHP is relevant to the problem?

Comment: @JanDvorak - Because I don't like to vote to close too quickly, I prefer to give the OP time to come back and clarify first. But as it happens, immediately after posting that comment I spotted what the error is so I posted an answer.

Comment: @nnnnnn even if the question didn't qualify as unclear - doesn't it still qualify as "typo / unrelated cause / unsearchable"?

Comment: @lin wait, what? What should it be then? `innerHtml`? No...

Comment: @JanDvorak - I don't really agree with closing all typo questions, so I don't tend to vote to close them. There's a difference between misspelling something in the sense of incorrect capitalisation and an actual typo where a letter is missed or something like that. (I do regularly vote to close for other reasons.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks for the explanation. If I understand correctly, that close reason is meant for questions where a person that finds the question on Google is unlikely to be helped by the answer. A person searching for "how to get javascript and PHP to work together" is unlikely to have a capitalisation issue in their code. Rather, he is likely to be interested in the interaction model between those two languages. Thus, I believe this question does qualify as a typo question. Remember the purpose of StackExchange is to create a repository of knowledge. I don't think this question helps that.

Comment: @JanDvorak - True. Certainly in this case the JS and HTML could've (and should've) been tested independently before posting here. I think the question could be "fixed" (or at least improved) by giving it a better title and adding the explanation I originally asked for above.

Comment: It is not fair that I'm the one subtracts vote. I'm new and I ignored the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is cAsE sEnSiTiVe. It should be `.innerHTML`, not `.innerhtml`:

```
echo '<select onchange="document.getElementById(\'ele\').innerHTML=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">';
// ..............................change this..................^^^^
```

Comment: @lin please show us your test case. Why do you think this doesn't work?

Comment: @lin - It _does_ work: http://jsfiddle.net/8WYZM/ I _did_ test before posting, just in case there was some other typo that I hadn't seen (there wasn't, at least not in the JS). You'll find that `.innerHTML` is well documented if you just do a simple Google search.

Comment: Yeye, in germany we would say. "Ich war aufn falschen Dampfer". Cheers :P

Comment: I tested the code of "nnnnnn" by correcting html "HTML" and anything more

Comment: This is the right answer for other users. Thank you all.